# Click element with different ID in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I wanna click on the Submit button on my homepage. Submit button has two different IDs for desktop and mobile view.
submit button and Submit.

How to click on the Submit button with two different IDs for the same URL.

I am aware that there is or condition I can use but can't make it work

`By.id("submitButton | Submit"));`

something like this.

Help, please

Comment: you could use By.xpath

Comment: As mentioned by @tgdavies, use By.xpath like this By.xpath("//*[@id='submitButton']|//*[@id='Submit']")

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks

Comment: @MillieAnneVolante Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `xpath` using `or` operator:

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='submitButton' or @id='Submit']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use xPath as suggested by others or alternatively you can use this approach:

```java
driver.findElement(new ByAll(By.id("submitButton"), By.id("Submit")));
```